Is this design effective for ensuring that only one power source is active when two power sources are connected?

I found a design online that originally used a P-channel MOSFET, but I swapped it for an N-channel MOSFET. I'm not sure if this was the right choice or if it will work as expected. Any advice would be appreciated.

If you used pmos then you could make it so that when there's voltage on one of the inputs, it cuts off the other, by connecting the primary supply to the the gate of the pmos in series with the secondary supply.

It depends what you mean by effective.
It barely does that job and poorly.
The FET is useless as it is never turned on, it is always off, and only the intrinsic diode inside is used so you could replace it with a diode. So it was not a good idea to replace a P-Fet with N-Fet.
Also, since one of the nets is named VBUS, it appears the other source is USB.
Having a 480uF capacitor hanging on USB exceeds the spec requirement of 10uF max input capacitance a lot and may even damage something if you hot-plug that to an USB source.
Also the diode is a Schottky diode. While it provides low forward drop, it may leak a lot current in reverse which is not a good thing.

Thank you for your response! I replaced the N-channel MOSFET with an AO3401A, which is a P-channel MOSFET. Regarding the 480µF capacitor, I assume you meant the 470µF and 100nF capacitors. These capacitors are part of the schematic for the power converter. Given the changes, should I consider replacing the entire power converter?

@Robert I don't understand - you have drawn schematics but in real life the power converter is a off-the-shelf module?

I used the schematics provided by the manufacturer. I don't know how I can send you the photo of the schematic because it doesn't let me paste it here but the photo is in my last question on this site.

@Robert add it in the question. You have two questions and neither of them has any photo. In any case you can't hot plug or plug anything with 470uF cap to USB. You cannot randomly attach some modules together and expect it will not damage your PC or phone charger or anything. The module also does not work with 5V input to make 5V output.

Sorry for asking so many questions, I am new to this site and to ee in general.  What I'm trying to do is design a PCB that can be powered by +12V to supply power to two servos (+5V) and the MCU (+3.3V). When programming the MCU, I still need the +12V connected to ensure there's enough power for the two servos. I'm not sure if this is the right approach or if I'm overcomplicating things.  Also are you able to see the photo in the original question and the one in my other question from my profile? They’re visible to me, but I’m wondering if others can see them. Thanks again for your help.

No you have two questions and neither contais a photo. If you need 12V present even while programming MCU, why combine 5V from USB and 12V  to begin with - why not simply power everything from 12V then?

After searching for a little bit I realized that SWO does not use the USB cable (I use SWD for programming and debugging), so the USB in this case is indeed useless. I am trying to figure right now why you can't see the photos.

I disconnected from mt account and searched my profile and my 2 questions and both of them have a photo. It might be a little miss communication, English is not my first language.

@Robert I misread - I expected a photo taken with a camera of some module, you did say a photo of schematics, meaning a screenshot.

So I think I will just take the USB out since I don't need it and leave only the +12V power source and leave the rest as it is since those capacitors don't bother me anymore. If I am not mistaken I will be able to program the MCU only with the power source (+12V) and SWD. Also I changed the N-channel MOSFET to a P-channel one (AO3401A). Thanks again for your help and I wish you a great day!
